# .find() all occurrences of the queried words across multiple fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an API that I am querying. I want to search using multiple words to return results where instances of the words exist in the values of the fields stored.

```js
const regex = new RegExp(req.query.search, "gi");
query.find({
    $or: [{ firstname: regex }, { lastname: regex }, { bio: regex }]
});
```

so If I queried: `/users?search=brian+teddy+bear`

I would expect the result to include Mr. Brian Teddy who has "a love of bears" as his bio. Instead nothing is returned. But then, If I search one of those words *singularly* he is returned. How would I go about returning Brian Teddy if multiple bits of information are queried in a search field?

Answer (score 0):

If I've undestrood correctly you can use this query:

Also note that `$options: "i"` is to do the regex case insensitive.

```
query.find({
  $or: [
    {
      firstname: {
        "$regex": "brian|teddy|bear",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    },
    {
      lastname: {
        "$regex": "brian|teddy|bear",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    },
    {
      bio: {
        "$regex": "brian|teddy|bear",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IHUx3igWdNE)

Also, note how regex is word separated by `|` (`brian|teddy|bear`). You can create your regex using JS concatenating your values from query param. Maybe something like this:

```js
var queryParams = "brian+teddy+bear"
var regex = queryParams.split("+").join("|")
console.log(regex)
```